# Invalid parameter number on Laravel subquery

Tags: laravel

When I run the below query I get the following error: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters.

```
$subQuery = DB::table('earliest_count')
        ->select('reporting_week')
        ->where('vendor_name', $vendorName);

$dates = DB::table('invoice')
          ->select('week_beginning_date', 'week_end_date')
          ->whereRaw(':sql BETWEEN `week_beginning_date` AND `week_end_date`', [':sql' => DB::raw("({$subQuery->toSql()})")])
          ->where('week_beginning_date', '<', $date)
          ->orderBy('week_beginning_date')
          ->limit(1)
          ->mergeBindings($subQuery)
          ->get();
```

If I replace the `whereRaw` with the following it works:

```
->whereRaw('(SELECT reporting_week FROM earliest_count WHERE vendor_name = "My Vendor") BETWEEN `week_beginning_date` AND `week_end_date`')
```

How can I get the subquery to work without having to write the exact query as a string?

**Edit**

I did try the following, and I get no errors but I don't get any results. (When I enter the subquery as a string I do get a result):

```
->whereRaw('? BETWEEN `week_beginning_date` AND `week_end_date`', [DB::raw("({$subQuery->toSql()})")])
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel doesn't use named placeholders, you should use `?` for placeholders and remove the name from the parameters array.

Like this:

```
->whereRaw('? BETWEEN `week_beginning_date` AND `week_end_date`', [DB::raw("({$subQuery->toSql()})"])
```

Comment: Thanks forgot to mention I tried that too. That way works but it does not give a result.  Entering the subquery manually gets me a result.  It's like somehow the parameters are not binding correctly.